# C++ Hello World does not work

Tags: c++

I am doing C++ to print "Hello World!" and "CS16 Winter 2016."in two lines. After I compile, when I input "./hello", it creates a program called hello. When I run this program, it should output the two expected line; but my one's just show me other things. I don't know what's wrong with my code.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have your `cout` lines commented out. How do you expect to get any output?

Comment: I've seen better trolls. You need to try harder.

Comment: Hi. You need to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and should strongly consider reading the [How to Ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Post code as text, not as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the // from before the cout lines. Two slashes (i.e., "//") tells the compiler "the rest of this line is a comment, so ignore it."

One other quick suggestion: use a code editor that does syntax highlighting. Then you'll visually see what's a comment, what's a keyword, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question: when I log out the terminal and log in again, how can I input the exist code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. The normal process when writing software, is to:
1. Edit the code in a code editor, and save the file
2. Compile the code
3. Run the code

If you use a good development environment (e.g., Xcode), then you can do all three without needing a terminal/console window.